# Proportional stacked bar graph in R

Tags: r, graph, stacked

I'm having big trouble creating this bar graph! I'm new to R and have tried my best here...

I want my Y-axis to be "count", X-axis to be "title", the 2 groups would be data before and after a certain date; "date".

**I've tried this to scale first:**

```
library(plyr)

a <- ddply(counter (can someone explain what actually goes here?), 
           "title", transform, percent_count = count / sum(count) * 100)
```

**Then:**

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=title, y=percent_count, fill= date)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I would really appreciate any help, I've really tried my best with this before seeking extra help :)

Comment: Can you show us your data with `dput(df)`?

Comment: This post is internally inconsistent in asking for counts at one point and proportions in the title.

Comment: The help files are there just for that..to help you.  If you're new to R, I would learn how to manipulate and plot data in base R before moving into `plyr` and `ggplot2`.  That's simply my opinion, though.